# oracle sql - update same table based on another attribute value

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have a table in oracle which has 4 attributes with the following values

```
attribute_a       attribute_b    attribute_c     attribute_d

      abcd1                 1              0
      abcd1                 2              1
      abcd1                 3              0

       def1                 1              1
       def1                 2              1
```

I want to update the attribute_d with 'logical AND' values into attribute_d depending on the values in attribute_c
i.e. for abcd1  the logical AND is 0. I want to update the table with values 0 for abcd1 in attribute_d
and for def1, I want to update the table with value 1 in attribute_d for def1. can I use MERGE to accomplish this and if anyone can give me a query greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean bitwise and instead.

Comment: Why do you want to update the table? It's generally a bad idea to store computed values like that. (Data inconsistency...) Create a view instead, that always has fresh attribute_d values, even after the other columns have been updated. (If you really must store attribute_d values, use triggers to handle it's updates.)

Answer (score 0):

First off, I agree with @jarlh's comment about storing computed values.

Solution:

```
UPDATE [TableName]
SET attribute d = (CASE WHEN attribute_b = attribute c THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```